# OpenLDAP Password Policy overlay error while loading

Tags: linux, configuration, ldap

I'm trying to load the password policy overlay but I'm having the following error:

```
ldapadd  -Wx -D "cn=Manager,cn=config"  -f overlay.ldif 
Enter LDAP Password: 
adding new entry "olcOverlay=ppolicy,olcDatabase={0}bdb,cn=config"
ldap_add: No such object (32)
    matched DN: cn=config
```

This is the contents of the file:

```
dn: olcOverlay=ppolicy,olcDatabase={0}bdb,cn=config
olcOverlay: ppolicy
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcPPolicyConfig
olcPPolicyDefault: cn=default,ou=Policies,dc=site,dc=com
olcPPolicyHashCleartext: TRUE
olcPPolicyUseLockout: FALSE
```

In the log I found:

```
config_add_internal: DN="olcOverlay=ppolicy,olcDatabase={0}bdb,cn=config" not child of DN="cn=config"
```

I'm using CentOS 6.3 and openldap-servers-2.4.23-26.el6_3.2.x86_64.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the records in the `cn=config` database of OpenLDAP use number prefixes (`{0}`, `{1}`, etc). So when you go to modify something in the `cn=config` database, you have to make sure you're using the right DN (Distinguished Name: the path to the record). In OpenLDAP when using `cn=config`, the first olcDatabase entry is usually the config database itself (`olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config`). On my specific system, my main database is `olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config`.

If you don't know the DN of the `olcDatabase` you need to modify, the only way to know is to do a search and look through the results.

---

As for what those numbers (the `{0}` bit) are, they serve 2 purposes.

1. They allow you to have multiple entries of the same name.
   You could have 2 `olcDatabase=bdb` databases, in which you'd have a problem as you cant have 2 entries with the same DN.
2. They allow ordering.
   The LDAP protocol does not care about order. But you can prefix RDNs with `{X}` to allow ordering. In this specific case, I can't think of any reason off hand why the databases need to be ordered. But there are other critical use cases, such as in `cn=schema,cn=config`. In `cn=schema`, a schema can define an object class which depends on an attribute from a previous schema. As such the schemes must be loaded in order.

Comment: Re: ordering - backend databases have historically been identified by the numeric index (implicit by the order of their definition) mostly for backup/restore purposes. Also, when multiple databases/suffixes are used, the subordinates must be defined before their superiors (parents).

Answer (score 1):

`olcDatabase={0}bdb,cn=config`

needs to be changed to

`olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config`

Comment: Thanks , that did the trick, but do not understand the difference between {0} and {2}